# Print to PDF - File Size

Tags: printing, files, pdf

I recently ditched MacOS completely and am quite happy with Ubuntu. I print all my invoices and reports to PDF files, from the print dialog, which works rather well.

Except one thing - the file size. Even a text only single page has about 5MB. I'm then using GhostScript, from the command line, to optimize the output. This extra step is rather annoying and very unfriendly for the average user.

How can I print with a dialogue to set the output parameters to manage the file size.

Comment: perhaps [edit] your question to include how the invoices and reports are produced in the first place since the options may be featured there...

Comment: What application do you use to produce and print invoices?

Comment: I'm mostly using OnlyOffice. But PDFs created with Scribus e.g. are also very large. A 10 page report with some graphics and photos has 20 MB. After GS optimizing for "print", it's down below 1 MB.

Comment: I have a similar issue with Ubuntu 22.04. I just upgraded last month from 20.04, and Save to PDF creates a 3.8MB sized PDF, whereas the same print used to be 50k a month ago (still on 20.04). One notable difference is that text in the large PDF can't be selected with the PDF viewer so I guess the new PDF printer curves down texts to vector somehow.

Comment: Strange enough! I'm also on Ubuntu 22, but never used Linux before, for such tasks. Although I'm rather familiar with it, since the early days. Would just be nice to have a framework, which handles PDF creation in an adequate way, like on other OSs.

Comment: I also don't really appreciate, that some admin edited my my original post. 

I was asking:

Wouldn't it be nice to have a dialog, to set the parameters for PDF creation in Ubuntu (or any other distro, whatsoever), just like in MacOS. 

I always despised this code-nazi behaviour, in the Linux community, especially on stackexchange.

P.S. I've been working in the publishing industry, since the early 90's. I've been a pioneer in PDF publishing. I've been leading projects at publishers sites, with thousands of Macs.

Cheers

Comment: I edited your OP to remove the rant element and turn it into a question which otherwise would have been flagged as off-topic and closed. Before ranting at me, read [ask] and apply to any future questions. 